# Do webtests need VS tester edition on the build server?

Tags: tfs, build-process

Using the TFS build server *without* VS 2008 Team System Tester Edition installed - is it possible to run a series of webtests as part of a build?

I know that Webtests can only be recorded using the Tester Edition of VS. Here's a [post about this](http://blogs.vertigosoftware.com/teamsystem/archive/2006/03/09/Simple_Web_Testing_with_Team_Test_Edition.aspx) from Jeff, back when he was at Vertigo.

I'm just trying to *run* the tests, though. Does that require the Tester Edition of VS to be installed, as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to have the tester's edition; the Developer Edition works, *as long as you can code and run those tests locally.*

I believe with the standard MSDN license, if you have Developer Edition, you can run a single build server with a copy of it.  There might be some extra limitations, such as who can run builds on the server; you should review your license agreement to see if there are any issues.